# Excel file read and save data in SQL Server database using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

How to read an Excel file's data and save it into SQL Server database using asp.net c#?

Answer (score 0):

See [OpenXML 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) from MS...

It is a free library that does NOT require office to be installed... you can read + write Office files including Excel and Word (Version 2007 and up...).

IF you need more features (like rendering to PDF etc.) then you would need some 3rd-party library...

For the SQL Server part you can ADO.NET / Entity Framework or whatever technology you want...